# ZeroMQ PUSH/PULL communication doesn't work via IPC, but it works via TCP

Tags: node.js, sockets, multiprocessing, zeromq

It was a task from a book called "**Node.js 8 the Right Way**".
You can see it below:

[image: https://pp.userapi.com/c850628/v850628437/164aec/sFdn3icXb7Y.jpg]

[image: https://pp.userapi.com/c850628/v850628437/164ae4/4x02I_it_v8.jpg]

That's my solution:

```js
'use strict';
const zmq = require('zeromq');
const cluster = require('cluster');

const push = zmq.socket('push');
const pull = zmq.socket('pull');

const cores_num = require('os').cpus().length;
let workers_num = 0;

push.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:9998');
pull.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:9999');
// push.bind('ipc://push.ipc');
// pull.bind('ipc://pull.ipc');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  for (let j = 0; j < cores_num; j++) {
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('online', (worker) => {
    console.log(`Worker with pid ${worker.process.pid} is created!`);
  });

  pull.on('message', (data) => {
    const response = JSON.parse(data.toString());

    if (response.type === 'ready') {
      if (workers_num >= 0 && workers_num < 3) {
        workers_num++;

        if (workers_num == 3) {
          console.log('Ready!');

          for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            push.send(JSON.stringify({
              type: 'job',
              data: `This message has id ${i}`
            }));
          }
        }
      }
    } else if (response.type === 'result') {
      console.log(data.toString());
    }
  });
} else {
  const worker_push = zmq.socket('push');
  const worker_pull = zmq.socket('pull');

  worker_pull.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:9998');
  worker_push.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:9999');
  // worker_pull.connect('ipc://push.ipc');
  // worker_push.connect('ipc://pull.ipc');

  worker_push.send(JSON.stringify({
    type: 'ready'
  }));

  worker_pull.on('message', data => {
    const request = JSON.parse(data);

    if (request.type === 'job') {
      console.log(`Process ${process.pid} got message ${request.data}`);
      worker_push.send(JSON.stringify({
        type: 'result',
        data: `This message is a response from process ${process.pid}`,
        time: Date.now()
      }));
    }
  });
}
```

As you can see, it works only when PUSH/PULL sockets and workers communicate via TCP, but I want to know the reason why it doesn't work via IPC.

**Update** ( ref: Condition 4 below "pathname **must** be writeable" ):
[image]
I hope that you will help me with finding a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Few things:

#### Your IPC path is incorrect:

You have `ipc://push.ipc` (2 slashes) you really need `ipc:///push.ipc`
The protocol is `ipc://` then you need the file path `/push.ipc`

#### File permissions:

Does your process have permission to write to the root directory? Unless you are running as root I would think not.

I would change the path to something like `/tmp/push.ipc` which in most systems is writable by all users.

In which case your url should be:

`ipc:///tmp/push.ipc`

#### Forking

I do not use node at all but based on my knowledge of other languages forking I think the whole program is run again in the different process/thread.

In this case isn't each worker trying to `bind()` again as the socket creation/bind code is outside of the `if (cluster.isMaster) {`

It should look like this I think

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {

  const push = zmq.socket('push');
  const pull = zmq.socket('pull');
  push.bind('ipc://push.ipc');
  pull.bind('ipc://pull.ipc');
  ....
}
```

Comment: Do you see the files created on the disk  (e.g /tmp/push.ipc) ?.  If they are there do an `ls -l` so we can see the permissions

Comment: Here it is, guys:
https://pp.userapi.com/c849332/v849332599/1dd387/JWw_dDhdfqU.jpg

Comment: the ipc files look ok but I have a question about your forking and sockets. I have updated my answer as its its needs more room to explain

Comment: You was absolutely right, thanks!
The problem was that I binded sockets outside the parent's process.

Thus, every worker was running these lines of code and binding push/pull sockets, what was a very rude mistake.

Comment: Anyways, it's interesting, how the hell did it work via TCP sockets. .-.

Comment: In the case of TCP as long as the bind of the master occured before the workers, the workers would just fail the bind but continue. IPC is a bit more tricky and multiple binds give undefined results sometime.  If your happy with the answer can you upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

> ### I want to know the reason why it doesn't work via IPC.

There are a few conditions for using **`ipc://`** transport-class for using the ZeroMQ Scalable Formal Communication Archetypes and get `.bind()/.connect()`-ed

1) The inter-process transport passes messages between local processes using a system-dependent IPC mechanism. The inter-process transport is currently **only implemented on operating systems that provide UNIX domain sockets.**

2) Both the `.bind()`-side and the `.connect()`-side need to meet at some feasible **address**:

```
          push.bind(    'ipc://push.sock'     ); // will never meet its counterparty
 // ------------------(--|||://^v^v^v^v^v^v^v )
   worker_pull.connect( 'ipc:///tmp/push.sock'); //         if used other ipc://-address
```

3) If any second process binds to an endpoint already bound by a process, this will succeed and the first process will lose its binding. In this behaviour, the `ipc://` transport-class is not consistent with the `tcp://` or `inproc://` transport-classes.

4) The endpoint-address pathname **must** be writable by the process. When the endpoint starts with /, e.g., ipc:///pathname, this will be an absolute pathname. If the endpoint specifies a directory that does not exist, the bind shall fail.

5) When the endpoint-address pathname starts with **`@`**, the abstract namespace shall be used. The abstract namespace is independent of the filesystem and if a process attempts to bind an endpoint already bound by a process, it will fail. See unix(7) for details.

6) `ipc://` transport-class pathnames have a maximum size that depends on the operating system. On Linux, the maximum is 113 characters including the "`ipc://`" prefix (107 characters for the real path name).

7) When a wild-card * endpoint specification was used in the `zmq_bind()`, the caller **should** use real endpoint obtained from the **`ZMQ_LAST_ENDPOINT`** socket option to unbind this endpoint from a socket using `zmq_unbind()`.

Comment: Yep, you're right. 
I've got an error with socket's paths, but it didn't change a thing. :)

Btw, my machine works on a Ubuntu distributive, so it must be OK. 

Do you have any ideas why it still doesn't work?

Comment: If all points 1 - 4 have been checked and positively met, then there is a reason to file an ipc:// transport-class related ticket at the maintainers' troubleshooting queue.